# MCQ on a function

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=\left( \ln \left( \frac{\left( 7x-x^{2} \right)}{12} \right) \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Choose correct options , more than one may be correct .

(a) $f$ is defined on $R^+$ and is strictly increasing.

(b)$f$ is defined on an interval of finite length and is strictly increasing

(c)range of function include 1

(d)$f$ is defined on an interval of finite of length and is bounded .

Now answer says (c) & (d)

I am getting (b) & (d) and that too when I don't take the natural domain of the function i.e. on all real values it could possibly be defined .

Here is the graph of the function

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D%5Cleft%28+%5Cln+%5Cleft%28+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28+7x-x%5E%7B2%7D+%5Cright%29%7D%7B12%7D+%5Cright%29+%5Cright%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%7D%7D&dataset=

How can the function be bounded when it approaches $-\infty$ from both sides .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worry not about Alpha. We are ultimately going to take a square root, so $$\ln\left(\frac{7x-x^2}{12}\right)$$
 has to be non-negative, that is, we must have 
$\frac{7x-x^2}{12}\ge 1$. Equivalently, we want $x^2-7x+12\le 0$, which happens only for $3\le x\le 4$.

Note that $f(x)$ is $0$ at $3$ and $4$, so cannot be strictly increasing.

Comment: Yes so , how can range contain 1 ?

Comment: It doesn't. The function $7x-x^2$ is pretty flat in the interval $[3,4]$, so dividing by $12$ gets us not far over $1$. The logarithm is therefore not much above $0$, taking the $3/2$-th power makes things worse.